# Is there a way to make some features more important than others in a SVM classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn` library to train the default SVM classifier on a bunch of data. My data has roughly 30 features. But I realize some of these features are "more important" than others. For example, I want the change in features 1, 2, and 3 to greatly impact the learning process, whereas, features 4 through 25 are useful information, but not as critical.

If I just multiply the numbers in features 1 to 3 by say, 100, it won't make much difference because I believe the algorithm normalizes the features anyway. So my question is, how can I give a weight to the features in an SVM classifier, so that some of them influence the learning and prediction more than others?

Here's the very crude version of the code I'm using:

```
clf = SVC(probability=True, gamma=0.1, C=1))
data = np.array([1, 4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7, 2, ... ])
target = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ... ])
clf.fit(data, target)
```

Comment: 'it won't make much difference because I believe the algorithm normalizes the features anyway. ' Yes, this is true, but you can switch the normalization off and do it yourself. If you set the scale of all variables to 1 except one that you set to 100, then that variables will be prioritized by the algorithm.

Comment: Why not let the algorithm figure it out?  It does, you know.

Comment: @user603 I didn't think of that. I'll have to see if their implementation allows switching off the normalization. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @jbowman Of course, I can. It's not clear though how much data the algorithm needs before it slowly realizes it.

Comment: @darksky: actually scooring through the docs, I do not think sklearn pre-scales the variables. You are suppose to do this yourself.

Comment: @Sycorax I'm not sure if that question answers mine. The kernel in the SVM I'm using is radial basis function which is different from the one suggested in the answer.

Comment: It's the same idea. $$K(x_i, x_j) = \exp(- (x_i - x_j)^\top \Gamma (x_i - x_j))$$ for diagonal, PD matrix $\Gamma$ instead of scalar $\gamma$, which is a generalization of the RBF to give individual weights to each feature, i.e. exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: If your question has been nominated for closure as a duplicate, but you have reasons why the proposed duplicate is actually not one, best to edit your question and explain that right there, so future close-voters will see it immediately.

Comment: @Sycorax Can you please explain what do you mean by $$\Gamma$$? The RBF is defined $$\exp\left(-\frac{\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x'}\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$. How would I change that to account for your positive-definite matrix D?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I understand that. But I am not sure yet if it answers mine, so I am asking for clarification.

Comment: This is just algebra. $|| x - x^\prime ||_2^2 = (x - x^\prime)^\top (x - x^\prime)$ by the definition of inner product. Denote $\gamma = 2\sigma^{-2}$. Now you have $$K(x,x^\prime) = \exp(-\gamma (x - x^\prime)^\top (x - x^\prime)).$$ This is the same as $$ K(x,x^\prime) = \exp(- (x - x^\prime)^\top (\gamma I)  (x - x^\prime)).$$ If you replace $\gamma I$ with a PD, diagonal matrix $\Gamma$, you rescale each feature by $\Gamma_{ii}$, which is the desired outcome.

Comment: @Sycorax "you rescale each feature by $\Gamma_{ii}$", is this a different effect than just scaling each feature like I proposed, eg. multiplying by 100, and then feeding it to SVM, performance-wise?

Comment: @darksky They're the same. Just note that if you want to rescale by $\Gamma_{ii}$, you should multiply each feature by $\Gamma_{ii}^{1/2}$ (left as an exercise for the reader).